# git, как перенести commit в другую ветку

Tags: git, commit

Что если ты в git уже сделал commit например в master, а потом понял что лучше его вынести в другую ветку(которой пока нет). Как сделать так что бы этого commit'а не было в master, а он появился в новой ветке, которую тоже необходимо создать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать следующим образом:

- создать новую ветку
- переключиться на нее и сделать git cherry-pick "commit-hash" (хэш номер того комита, который нужно перенести)
- вернуться на мастер и сделать git reset HEAD~1 (комит, предыдущий тому, на который указывает HEAD)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли

Answer (score 2):

как обычно, напоминание: «ветка» («branch») в программе *git* — это плавающий указатель на коммит (есть ещё фиксированные указатели — метки («tags), речь дальше не о них).

---

что у нас есть? цепочка («история», «history») взаимосвязанных коммитов (стрелками указана связь коммитов — в направлении от потомка к родителю):

```
       б → а → … → самый_первый_коммит
```

и есть указатель на коммит под названием «ветка1» (указывает на самый «свежий» коммит «б»):

```
ветка1
       б → а → …
```

что нам надо? переместить указатель «ветка1» на коммит «а», а заодно создать новый указатель «ветка2», указывающий на коммит «б»:

```
ветка2    ветка1
       б → а → …
```

---

проще начать с конца — сначала создать новый указатель («ветка2») как дубликат существующего указателя («ветка1»):

```
$ git checkout -b ветка2 ветка1
```

а потом переставить указатель «ветка1» на коммит «а» (ну, или любой другой в истории, при необходимости).

тут много разных вариантов. для данного случая, когда переставляемый указатель не является текущим, можно использовать команду `branch`:

```
$ git branch -f ветка1 хэш_коммита_«а»
```

опция `-f` (`--force`) в данном случае обязательна, т.к. изменяем **существующий** указатель. без неё программа *git* выдаст ошибку и ничего не изменит.

---

p.s. контролировать процесс удобно командой `log` с опцией `--all`:

```
$ git log --all
```

в выводе будут присутствовать **и** имена указателей возле тех коммитов, на которые они в данный момент указывают.

Answer (score 1):

1. Переименовать локальный мастер в желаемую новую ветку.
2. Удалить tracking reference.
3. Запушить.